# setting property values in Multi-dimensional object array

Tags: javascript, object, multidimensional-array

I`m trying to initialize multi-array *sudoku[9][9]* which is consist of *cell*
when I run *sudoku.initialize()*, all *row*, *col*, *box* in *sudoku[x][y]*s are 8,8,9 each.

```
  var cell = {
    sol: 0,
    row: 0,
    col: 0,
    box: 0,
    candi: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
};


var sudoku = {}
sudoku = new Array(9);
for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    sudoku[i] = new Array(9);
}
for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        sudoku[i][j] = cell;
    }
}
sudoku.initialize = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            sudoku[i][j].row = i;
            sudoku[i][j].col = j;
            if (i < 3) {
                if (j < 3)
                    sudoku[i][j].box = 1;
                else if (2 < j && j < 6)
                    sudoku[i][j].box = 2;
                else if (5 < j)
                    sudoku[i][j].box = 3;
            }
            else if (2 < i && i < 6) {
                if (j < 3)
                    sudoku[i][j].box = 4;
                else if (2 < j && j < 6)
                    sudoku[i][j].box = 5;
                else if (5 < j)
                    sudoku[i][j].box = 6;
            }
            else if (5 < i)
                if (j < 3)
                    sudoku[i][j].box = 7;
                else if (2 < j && j < 6)
                    sudoku[i][j].box = 8;
                else if (5 < j)
                    sudoku[i][j].box = 9;
        }
    }
}
sudoku.print=function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            document.write(sudoku[i][j].col + "&nbsp");
        }
        document.write("\n");
    }
}
sudoku.initialize();`
```

I guess there is misunderstand for multi-dementional array in javascript.

```
 sudoku[2][2].box=1
    1
    sudoku[4][8].box=2
    2
    sudoku[2][2].box
    2
    sudoku[3][3].box
    2
```

cuz I`m beginner for javascript, this codes could be ridiculous. but anyway you can catch what I meant.

Comment: All 81 items in your array point to the same object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All 81 items in your multi-dimensional array point to the same object, because of this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        sudoku[i][j] = cell;
    }
}
```

You make `sudoku[i][j]` store a reference to the same object `cell`.
When you later try to modify / access values in `sudoku[2][2]`, `sudoku[3][3]`, `sudoku[4][8]`, you actually work with the same object.

You need to create a new object for every cell.
Changing your code this way should help:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        sudoku[i][j] = {
            sol: 0,
            row: 0,
            col: 0,
            box: 0,
            candi: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
        };
    }
}
```

You also don't need so many `if`s in your `initialize` method.
Some math and integer division / modulus would do all the magic in two lines of code ;)

```js
function Cell(row, col)
{
  this.col = col;
  this.row = row;
  this.sol = 0;
  this.box = Math.ceil(row / 3) * 3 + Math.ceil(col / 3) - 3;
  this.candidates = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
}

function Sudoku()
{
  this.rows = new Array(9);
  for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) 
  {
    this.rows[i] = new Array(9);
    for (var j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
      this.rows[i][j] = new Cell(i, j);
    }
  }
  
  this.print = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            document.write(this.rows[i][j].row + "/" + this.rows[i][j].col + "&nbsp");
        }
        document.write("<br/>");
    }
  };
}

var sudoku = new Sudoku();
sudoku.print();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are assigning the same object to every one of your cells. Because objects in Javascript are stored by reference (not by value), doing

```
sudoku[1][2] = cell;
```

Essentially makes `sudoku[1][2]` and `cell` mean the same thing. You need to create a new cell object for every one of the positions in `sudoku`. There is a lot of material available on how to define "classes" in Javascript and instantiate objects, see for example:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new

Although there are other approaches possible, for example you could clone the object, use prototypes, etc.